# Having a Dll made by dot net , is there any way to distinguish its methods?

Tags: .net, dll, methods

Having a Dll made by dot net , is there any way to distinguish its methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/). Or simply add a reference and explore using Object Browser in Visual Studio.